# How to merge pandas Series with DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

I created a pd.Series without columns name, look like this:

```
Data Inicial                          2019-12-02
Data Final                            2019-12-06
Rentabilidade do Período                 0.2863%
CDI Acumulado no Período                    4.9%
Rentabilidade Relativa                   5.8419%
Evolução do Patrimônio              -0.000454579
Menor Retorno Diário        2019-12-06: (-0.24%)
Maior Retorno Diário         2019-12-05: (0.25%)
dtype: object
```

I had a DataFrame look like this:

```
Data  Ganhos Acumulados
1944 2019-12-02           0.000000
1945 2019-12-03           0.189677
1946 2019-12-04          -0.155147
1947 2019-12-05           0.248015
1948 2019-12-06          -0.236190
```

What I need: I need to create a DataFrame with both data structures, because after this, I will convert it to an HTML and plot in my frontend.

The new DataFrame should be looking like this:

```
Data Inicial                          2019-12-02
Data Final                            2019-12-06
Rentabilidade do Período                 0.2863%
CDI Acumulado no Período                    4.9%
Rentabilidade Relativa                   5.8419%
Evolução do Patrimônio              -0.000454579
Menor Retorno Diário        2019-12-06: (-0.24%)
Maior Retorno Diário         2019-12-05: (0.25%)
2019-12-02                              0.000000
2019-12-03                              0.189677
2019-12-04                             -0.155147
2019-12-05                              0.248015
2019-12-06                             -0.236190
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the `'Date'` column of your `pd.DataFrame` as its index. Then you just have to concatenate along the index your original `pd.Series` with the `"Ganhos Acumulados"` column of your `pd.DataFrame`, which is by definition a `pd.Series`.

```
df_as_series = df.set_index(['Date'])['Ganhos Acumulados']
result = pd.concat([<your_series>, df_as_series])
```

Comment: In this way, I received them error message: **f"Cannot remove {len(level)} levels from an index with {self.nlevels} "
ValueError: Cannot remove 1 levels from an index with 1 levels: at least one level must be left.**

Comment: what are the columns in your dataframe ?

Comment: I have index "Date" and values for Columns "Ganhos Acumulados"...

Comment: then, `df = df.set_index('Date')['Ganhos Acumulados']`and then `result = pd.concat([<your_series>, df])`:)

Comment: Please do not post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality and are more likely to attract upvotes.